# Find matches to a value in a range and get first cell and first column values for each match google app script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Currently working on code, but cant make it work.

terms: have a table where y: names, x:dates
need: if there is value 'yes' in the cell, then take name and date at intersection and write it down somewhere as list (the Result below)

```
// -- Table:

      1 Sep 2022      2 Sep 2022    3 Sep 2022  4 Sep 2022  5 Sep 2022  6 Sep 
Name 1  yes                       yes   
Name 2                yes                       yes
Name 3                             yes                  
Name 4                                                      yes             
Name 5                                                              yes         
Name 6                     yes      
                                
// -- Result:                               
Name 1  1 Sep 2022                          
Name 1  7 Sep 2022                          
Name 2  ..                          
Name 4                              
Name 5                              
Name 6
```

// -- My code:

```
function nameAndDate () {
  var sheetTable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('table');
  var lastRow = sheetTable.getLastRow();
  var range = sheetTable.getRange('A1:AF'+ lastRow);
  var match = 'yes'
  var values = range.getValues();
  values.forEach(function(value){
    if (value.includes(match)){
      var cellRow = sheetTable.getRange.getRow;
      var cellColumn = sheetTable.getRange.getColumn;
      var date = sheetTable.getRange(1,cellColumn).getValue();
      var name = sheetTable.getRange(cellRow,1).getValue();

      sheetTable.getRange('A'+ lastRow).setValue(name);
      sheetTable.getRange('B' + lastRow).setValue(date);
    
    }  
  })
}
```

will appreciate any help please.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

Use loops with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  and `.filter` to create a new 2D array and `setValues()` the modified array.

```
const values = range.getValues(),
  out = ((i) =>
    ((data) => {
      while (++i < values.length) {
        const row = values[i];
        data.push(
          values[0]
            .filter((h, j) => row[j] === 'yes')
            .map((header) => [row[0], header])
        );
      }
      return data;
    })([]))(0).flat();
console.log(out);
sheetTable.getRange(20, 1, out.length, 2).setValues(out)
```

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const values = [
['', 'Sep 1', 'Sep 2', 'Sep 3'],
['Name 1', 'yes', '', 'yes'],
['Name 2', '', 'yes', ''],
  ],
  out = ((i) =>
((data) => {
  while (++i < values.length) {
    const row = values[i];
    data.push(
      values[0]
        .filter((h, j) => row[j] === 'yes')
        .map((header) => [row[0], header])
    );
  }
  return data;
})([]))(0).flat();
console.log(out);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```